# AWS RDS-MySQL showing more storage usage than expected/actual DB size

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, logging, storage, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS - MySQL instance, and it has one database.

Instance Class: db.r6g.xlarge
Engine version 8.0.17
Storage: 100 GB

The database size is only 24GB, but the AWS console shows only a free space of 8GB. I can't find out what is consuming this 92GB of space, even though the DB size is only around 25GB,

The output of the following command gave me the DB size in GB.

SELECT table_schema, ROUND(SUM(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024/1024,2) "size in GB" FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC;

[image]

Output of `SHOW MASTER LOGS;`

[image]

Ouput of `select table_name, round(data_length/1024/1024) as data_length_mb,  round(data_free/1024/1024) as data_free_mb  from information_schema.tables  where round(data_free/1024/1024) > 250  order by data_free_mb;`

[image]

Any help to find out what is consuming the rest of the storage space would be really helpful?

Comment: Did you go through this document? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/view-storage-rds-mysql-mariadb/

Comment: I am facing same issue. I have 20GB SSD RDS, Total database table size is 0.1 GB only but it shows me used as 18.111 GB-Mo